# How to set cache headers for files accessed directly

Tags: asp.net, caching, iis, iis-7, browser-cache

I have a server that serves WAV file to Twilio and I am having some problems to set the cache to those files.
My problem is that the files have different expiration date, some shouldn't be cached, some should be cached for a day, some for a month and so on.
At the moment I was able to set to not cache any of the files using the IIS Output Caching, however now I need to set some caches.
Basically Twilio request the WAV files calling it directly, for example, http://mywebsite.com/mysoundwithoutcache.wav as well as http://mywebsite.com/mysoundwith1daycache.wav and so on.

My question is how do I add this headers to those files that are been called directly?

I am using IIS 7 and ASP.NET

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The way to apply settings just to a certain files is to use the location tag, in your web.config add a new node under configuration:

```
<location path="cache_me.wav">
<system.webServer>
    <caching>
        <profiles>
            <add extension="*.wav" policy="CacheForTimePeriod" kernelCachePolicy="DontCache" duration="01:00:00" />
        </profiles>
    </caching>        
</system.webServer>
</location>
```

Unfortunately I don't think you can use wildcards in the path attribute, so you one of these sections for each file. If would be easier to put all files to be cached into a separate folder, then you can get away with a single location node.

Having said all that, you should not worry about output caching for your waves files, static files are cached by IIS automatically.

Comment: I will try this, I do have lots of file but it will be easier to do a big xml with all the files than try to change the application at this stage. I am confuse about what you said about IIS cache the wav files automatically. My problem been if I don't set the cache to DontCache when I upload new messages Twilio still using the old version of the file and I must set to no cache to the problem to go away